# How to remove/revert commited changes to local git repo

Tags: git, commit, revert

I've committed some changes to local git repo with 
    command git commit -m "Change X"

Question: Is it possible to revert/remove this change from local git and my working directory?

I know I can use  git commit ammend to rewrite this commit, but I want to delete it, I dont want to put it to remote repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

Undo your commit, files and your index.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Undo your commit but leave your files and your index.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Comment: OK it works:) ... I tried  git reset --hard HEAD, why it was wrong:)?

Comment: The last three commits (HEAD, HEAD^, and HEAD~2) were bad and you do not want to ever see them again. Do not do this if you have already given these commits to somebody else. --> http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: Is is possible to remove this change from local repo and ADDITIONALLY bring all these changes back to working directory,in order to make working directory like before last "git add .." ?

Comment: Try without the `--hard` or with `--soft` instead. But have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866485/1112326, it explains everything pretty well :)

Comment: @Pawel Of course it is possible. Like this ``git reset --soft HEAD~1``

Comment: @Dotterer Thanks, it is wery good link:)!